# How to edit this Deployment Yaml to have write permission in container

Tags: kubernetes

When i deploy this Deployment for sock-shop
[Yaml for sock-shop](https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/complete-demo.yaml)

but it does not give me write permission in the container so i cannot even write in it

```
$ kubectl exec -it carts-5496ffc4b6-5xr68 -n sock-shop -- sh
/usr/src/app $ apk add python
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied
/usr/src/app $ echo "Hello world" > sample.txt
sh: can't create sample.txt: Permission denied
/usr/src/app $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the pod as root to be able to get that permission.Edit the yaml and add below in the `carts` deployment

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
```

Recommended option would be run `apk add python` in the Dockerfile itself and create a image with it installed already.

Answer (score 1):

In the Dockerfile of the container that runs the carts micro-service https://github.com/microservices-demo/carts/blob/master/Dockerfile , add the below line,

```
USER root
```

This will make sure root permission is added and apk add may work.